# Function to check if externally hosted textfile contains string acting slow- Node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following code, which will retrieve a text file from an external server, and search the file for a specific string.

**The function:**

```
function checkStringExistsInFile(String, cb) {
var opt = {
    host: 'site.com',
    port: 80,
    path: '/directory/data.txt',
    method: 'GET',
};

var request = http.request(opt, function(response){
    response
    .on('data', function(data){
        var string = data+"";
        var result = ((string.indexOf(" "+ String +" ")!=-1)?true:false);
        cb(null, result);
    })
    .on('error', function(e){
        console.log("-ERR: Can't get file. "+JSON.stringify(e));
        if(cb) cb(e);
    })
    .on('end', function(){
        console.log("+INF: End of request");
    });
});
request.end();
}
```

**And this is where I call the function, and do something with the results.**

```
checkStringExistsInFile(String, function(err, result){
    if(!err) {
        if(result) {
            //there was a result
        } else {
            //string not present in file
        }
    } else {
        // error occured
    }
});
```

This worked great in the beginning (small text file), but my textfile is getting larger (4000 characters+) and this is not working anymore.

What can I do to solve this? Should I safe the temporary save the file on my server first, should I open the file as a stream?

It would be appreciated if you can support your answer with a relevant example. Thanks in advance!

Comment: "not working anymore" means what? What happens instead of what you expect? Does it raise errors? Do the call backs never fire? It is just slower than it used to be?  What's the problem, _specifically?_

Comment: `(condition ? true : false)` is somewhat redundant, as (condition) already return `true` if it is true and `false` if it is false.

Comment: @Alex It takes so long to respond, I get a 502 error when I execute the script.

Comment: @Mdlc I just made an edit to make sure it callbacks only once.

Comment: Great, the code is now running as expected, I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Documentation :**

> If you attach a data event listener, then it will switch the stream into flowing mode, and data will be passed to your handler as soon as it is available.
>
> If you just want to get all the data out of the stream as fast as possible, this is the best way to do so.

http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_data

Data event is emitted as soon as there are data, even if the stream is not completely loaded. So your code just look for your string in the first lines of your stream, then callbacks.

**What to do ?**

Your function should only call callback on the `end()` event, or as soon as it finds something.

```
function checkStringExistsInFile(String, cb) {
  var opt = {
    host: 'site.com',
    port: 80,
    path: '/directory/data.txt',
    method: 'GET',
  };

  var request = http.request(opt, function(response){
    var result = false;
    response
    .on('data', function(data){
        if(!result) {
            var string = data+"";
            result = (string.indexOf(" "+ String +" ")!=-1);
            if(result) cb(null, result);
        }
    })
    .on('error', function(e){
        console.log("-ERR: Can't get file. "+JSON.stringify(e));
        if(cb) cb(e);
    })
    .on('end', function(){
        console.log("+INF: End of request");
        cb(null, result)
    });
  });
  request.end();
}
```